# How do I fix this error SDL2/SDL.h: No such file or directory?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, makefile, sdl-2

so I am trying to install SDL2 for c++ and I always get the error

`fatal error: SDL2/SDL.h: No such file or directory`

I followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jUZZC9UXyFs. I already looked up several stack overflow questions and other websites but none of them could help me.

For this line I get an error:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
```

This is how I set up all files in the working directory.

[working directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoMIA.png)

In the include path I have those lines

```
${workspaceFolder}/**
${workspaceFolder}/src/include
```

This is the line I have in the Makefile:

```
all:
    g++ -I src/include -L src/lib -o main main.cpp -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2
```

In general, cpp works flawless for me. I installed the 64bit version mingw version of SDL2.

Comment: In VSCode you need to edit your `tasks.json` and your `c_cpp_properties.json` to add the include path if you are not using an extension like CMakeTools or Makefile tools.

Comment: You should explain what settings you have made. No one will view a video to try to decipher if it is correct or if you somehow did not follow the instructions. Besides the purpose of a question at StackOverflow is to help future readers with the same problem. Most likely if someone with this problem has to view a video to determine if their steps are the same as you they are likely to just skip the question.

Comment: this is my tasks.json https://postimg.cc/K1jj18VN and this is my c_cpp_properties.json https://postimg.cc/6Tzvj3kr, what do I have to edit?

Comment: Please add the 2 files as text. Its a site requirement: [https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: So I installed SDL2-devel-2.24.0-mingw.zip
on https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/releases/tag/release-2.24.0.
Next I made the folder "src" and put their the "include" and "lib" folders from the folder I downloaded from github. Next I put the SDL2.dll file into the working directory from the "bin" folder I downloaded. Then I created the makefile and a simple cpp file, thats all

Comment: It's better to edit your question and add the relevant info to your question directly: long threads of comments are not easy to read.  And remove the links to videos and images they will likely go away in the future and just be broken links when someone else comes along trying to solve this problem.

Comment: There's absolutely nothing magic whatsoever about how compilers find include files.  It's completely trivial: for each directory provided with `-I` on the command line, the path in your `#include` is added to it.  If it exists, it's used.  If not, the next `-I` directory is tried.  If not found, error.  So, in your case, does the file `src/include/SDL2/SDL.h` (case sensitive if you're on a case-sensitive filesystem) exist?  If not, that's your problem.  Where _is_ the `SDL.h` file?  If it does exist then somehow your working directory is changing when you run the build.